# How to generate different random 100000 numbers as money type between (0-15000) in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

I have seen some similar questions, and came up with something like this:

```
select RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
```

but the question is when I set it into money type, it loses some digits and then some rows will be the same again.

Following are my entire codes,please give me some advice.

```
if(exists(select * from sysobjects where name='dump') )
    drop table [dump]

    --create the table
    CREATE table [dump]
    (id int ,name varchar(50), price money)

    declare @p money=0
    set @p= RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*15000
    --set initial value
    INSERT INTO dump
    values(@i,newID(),@p)
    --insert the rows
    WHILE(@i<100000)

    begin
    set @p=RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*15000
    set @i+=1
        INSERT INTO dump
        values(@i,newID(),@p) 
        print 'the nth row：'+cast(@i as varchar(15)) 
    end
```

Comment: Please always tag your DMBS, especially when dealing with data types

Comment: Thank you for your comment, sorry for my careless

Comment: To clarify - are you trying to generate and store 100000 `unique` random numbers?

Comment: yes, I have also tried not in(), but it's too slow.

Comment: Don't insert a number in `dump` if it already exists and keep a counter of unique values until the row count in `dump` reaches 100,000

Comment: or you could put a unique constraint on the price field and use a `begin try .. catch`

Answer (score 1):

This will generate 100K unique values as a money type.  This ran in 20 seconds on my server.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dump') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #dump

CREATE TABLE #dump (Value MONEY)
CREATE INDEX [IXDUMP] ON #dump(Value)

DECLARE @i INT, @val MONEY
SET @i=1

WHILE @i <= 100000 /* SET THIS TO DESIRED COUNT */
BEGIN
    SELECT @val=CONVERT(MONEY,RAND()*15000)

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #dump WHERE Value=@val)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #dump(Value) 
        SELECT @val

        SET @i=@i+1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT '*'
        /* DO NOTHING, GO AGAIN, WITH SAME @i VALUE */
    END
END

/* DUPE VALUE CHECK */
SELECT Value
FROM #dump
GROUP BY Value
HAVING COUNT(2)>1

/* COUNT CHECK */
SELECT COUNT(2)
FROM #dump
```